# Shadowing in version 4.5

Tags: f#, shadowing

I started to study F# language.
I am using VS Community 2017. F# 4.5

I have a question about shadowing.
Looks like it doesn't work for me. When I use the same name bindings it tells "Duplicate definition of value 'x'".
What is wrong with the code?

```
let x = "one"
let x = "second"
let x = "third"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't shadow values at the module level.

You can shadow values inside some other scope like a function:

```
let f () =
    let x = "one"
    let x = "second"
    let x = "third"
    x
```